# Ошибка в процедуре: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть процедура, которая возвращает откртытый курсор. Если `I_ID IS NULL`, то процедура должна возвращать все записи:

```
PROCEDURE GETPERSON(I_ID IN NUMBER, I_STARTDATE IN DATE,I_ENDDATE IN DATE, RC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS--ADMINKA
    BEGIN
    IF I_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
    OPEN RC FOR
        SELECT
            NAME,
            AGE
        FROM PERSON S
       WHERE  S.ID = I_ID;
       ELSE
         SELECT NAME, AGE FROM PERSON;
      END IF;
    END GETPERSON;
```

Но выдает такую ошибку:

> Error: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT

Что не так, и как можно исправить?

Comment: Курсор не может быть просто SELECT - ибо некуда.

Comment: Для описанной задачи ни IF, ни даже процедура не нужны - просто `SELECT NAME, AGE FROM PERSON WHERE S.ID = COALESCE(I_ID, S.ID);`

Comment: @Akina если I_ID null то тогда должен возвращаться все записи,

Comment: Ну а у меня что, по-Вашему, получится, а? если `I_ID IS NULL`, то ещё при построении плана `WHERE S.ID = COALESCE(I_ID, S.ID)` будет преобразовано в `WHERE S.ID = COALESCE(NULL, S.ID)`, далее в `WHERE S.ID = S.ID` и, наконец, в `WHERE TRUE`. Обращаю внимание - это будет сделано ещё при построении плана, т.е. до выполнения запроса.

Comment: А что до процедур, они ничего возвращать не могут, особенно выборки. Тут могут помочь табличные функции https://www.fors.ru/upload/magazine/07/http_text/w_dev_pipelined_tf.html  Хотя в данном конкретном случае, это конечно не нужно, так как все делается одним запросом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В оператор открытия курсора [OPEN-FOR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/OPEN-FOR-statement.html) нельзя передать два запроса по условию в `IF-ELSE`. Исправить можно так:

```
create or replace package body pack as
    procedure getperson (id number, rc out sys_refcursor) is
    begin
        open rc for 
            select * 
            from person s
            where s.id = coalesce (getperson.id, s.id);
    end getperson;
end;    
/

Package Body PACK compiled
```

Но так лучше не делать - это плохой дизайн. Прочтя имя процедуры и передаваемые ей параметры: "верни мне персону к заданнаму `Id`", никто не станет ожидать, что если `Id` неопределенно (`null`), то процедура вместо пустого результата вернёт все записи.

Поэтому, правильнее надо сделать так:

```
create or replace package pack as
    procedure getPerson (id number, rc out sys_refcursor);
    procedure getAllPersons (rc out sys_refcursor);
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    procedure getPerson (id number, rc out sys_refcursor) is
    begin
        open rc for 
            select * 
            from person s
            where s.id = getperson.id;
    end getperson;
    procedure getAllPersons (rc out sys_refcursor) is
    begin    
        open rc for select * from person;
    end getAllPersons;
end;    
/
```

Запустить тест и получить результат:

```
var rc refcursor
exec pack.getPerson (1, :rc);

        ID NAME                            
---------- --------------------------------
         1 aaa                             

exec pack.getAllPersons (:rc);

        ID NAME                            
---------- --------------------------------
         1 aaa                             
         2 bbb                             
         3 ccc
```

---

На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0cc1a1ddcdc662d93094f6a371b5cceb).